# line graph with histogram underlaid and on side

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is perhaps an unusual graph that I am trying to make, so I've attached an illustration. I'm not sure if it is possible in matplotlib, so I thought I'd ask here for how to do it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQucW.jpg

Basically I'd like to plot a histogram (with `hist()`) on its side and then on top, overlay a line graph (with `plot()`), keeping the axis the same for the y on both sides.

Additionally I think it would only work if the histogram can have a lower opacity. Not sure if opacity can be set per plot instead of per figure.

Code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
line = [0.2, 0.3, 0.37, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.72, 0.75, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.795] 
distribution = [0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8]

plt.hist(distribution, orientation='horizontal')
plt.plot(range(len(line)), line, color='grey')

plt.savefig("test.png")
```

The histogram doesn't show up.

How can I do this?

Comment: So is the problem that you haven't figured out how to share the X axis, or just the opacity of the histogram?

Comment: sorry, I should clarify. the problem is how to 1) make sideways histogram on right, 2) how to decrease its opacity, and 3) overlay line plot. no need to share x-axis at all.

Comment: The opacity is called "alpha" - values are from 0-1, with 1 being opaque. I am having trouble with the histogram sideways, let alone on the right.

Comment: I don't understand how the bar length relate to time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use `twinx`/`twiny` twice to get two independent axes (there are probably ways to do this *with out* making a un-used middle axes, but this takes care a bunch of the behind-the-scenes details for you):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

line = [0.2, 0.3, 0.37, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.72, 0.75, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.795]
distribution = [0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax3 = ax2.twiny()

ax.plot(line)
ax.set_xlabel('line xaxis')
ax.set_ylabel('line yaxis')

ax3.hist(distribution, orientation='horizontal', alpha=.5)
ax3.invert_xaxis()
ax3.set_xlabel('hist xaxis, note where 0 is')
# note this needs to be ax2 due to subtle overlay issues....
ax2.set_ylabel('hist yaxis')
plt.draw()
```

You will have to play with the details of the axis (limit, labels, ticks ect), but `ax` and `ax3` are independent and you can apply the standard tactics to each independently.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used your code, and it rendered just fine, but then I switched to plotting using the axes to be a little bit more canon and a little less surprising. When you plot using axes, you generate an Artist object, but when you plot using plt, you generate a list of Artist objects.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = plt.gca()

line = [0.2, 0.3, 0.37, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.72, 0.75, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.795] 
distribution = [0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8]

ax.hist(distribution, orientation='horizontal', alpha=.5)
ax.plot(np.linspace(0,4,len(line)), line, color='grey', linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Beyond that, it's not clear what other functionality you'd like to see! There are many great tools within matplotlib, and having an axis-centric perspective is likely to make things a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial solution - I used a bar chart instead of a histogram because I couldn't figure out how to do the histogram sideways and overlaid.

```
from pylab import figure, show
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos_hist = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 10*np.random.rand(len(people))

x_for_line = np.linspace(0,10)
y_for_line = np.cos(x_for_line)

fig = figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()


ax1.plot(x_for_line, y_for_line)
ax2.barh(y_pos_hist, performance, alpha=0.2)
#alpha = 0.2 is what changes the opacity of the bars

plt.yticks(y_pos_hist, people)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The bar chart part is from [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.html)

[Consider this example, too](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/scatter_hist.html)

Comment: hmm, any way to share the y axises? and yeah having a histogram on right is ideally what I'd like to change number of bins, etc.